# When looking at a transmission, how can I know if there is a LSD?

Tags: transmission, dodge, neon, lsd

How can I know if there is an LSD installed on a transmission from a Dodge Neon 2003? For what indicators should I look for?.

[image: Transmission from a Dodge Neon 2003]

Comment: i think generally these things use all the factory transmission housings, so to tell the difference you'd have to open it up.

Comment: Are you asking in terms of knowing whether it may have been modified? LSDs (limited slip differentials, for those wondering) were offered by Dodge through Mopar as an aftermarket accessory, but they were not originally installed on any SRT-4s in that year (that I know of).

Comment: Yes I guess I'm looking to see if there is an aftermarket LSD. I'm really not an expert on car engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least one halfshaft available, you can turn one side. If the other side (might need someone to help you look) goes the same way, it's at least a limited-slip.

Comment: Would all LSD types necessarily exhibit this behavior when turned slowly (by hand) with very little torque (again, by hand?). My understanding is that many types of LSD require a significant difference in either wheelspeed or wheel torque in order to lock up.

Comment: Torsens don't, IIRC. However, if it does go the same way (or even stay still), it is an LSD. If it doesn't, it doesn't automatically eliminate it.

Comment: Ah, also you'll need the transmission in neutral to test this. Otherwise the opposite wheel will be forced to go the opposite way. If I'm thinking this through correctly.